# Is it not correct to use 逗号 (punctuation) in a place where 顿号 should be used?

Tags: punctuation

In so many cases I have used 逗号（，） to enumerate a list, which 顿号（、) should be used instead. For example:

> 我要去食品杂货店买**苹果，香蕉，和西瓜**。

However, the correct punctuation should be 顿号:

> 我要去食品杂货店买**苹果、香蕉、和西瓜**。

The reason is just that I could not type in it in my Mac.

So my questions are:

- Is it not correct to use 逗号 to enumerate a list? Or even though it is not correct, nonetheless is it actually used frequently among natives?
- What kind of impressions would I make if I use 逗号 in cases where 顿号 should be used?
- Does it have a chance of making a confusion if I use 逗号? In what kind of cases is it acceptable, and in what kind of cases should I refrain from using it?

Comment: You can type it on your Mac! Just switch your input to source to Pinyin and press the back slash \ key!

Comment: btw, the last 顿号 (before 和) is unnecessary. This might be a bigger problem than using 逗号 : )

Comment: @Sweeper I didn't know that! Thanks for the greatest tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, 顿号 should be used to punctuate for **words** enumerating.

As we all text on computers today, it's more convenient to just type a comma, instead of 顿号. Most of time, it's acceptable nowadays unless some would nitpick.

In theory, 顿号 would pause shorter than a comma.

Comment: Sorry for being late to respond, but what do you mean "pause shorter"?

Comment: a shorter pause...